# Extracting specific columns from a file to create new file in python

Tags: python

I have a file that looks something like this:

```
o 345644 0 0 0 1
0 454545 0 0 2 2
0 423233 0 0 1 1
. .      . . . .
. .      . . . .
. .      . . . .
```

What I would like to do is extract column two and column 6 to create a text file. I wrote the following code but the output file I am getting only contains the second column. The desired output I am would like is a new file that looks like this:

newfile.txt

```
 345644 1
 454545 2
 423233 1
 .      .
 .      .
 .      .
```

Here is my code :

```
dta_2path = open("file.txt","r")
ws_2= open("newfile.txt", "w")

for line in dta_2path:
    if line.strip():
       ws_2.write("\t".join(line.split()[1:2]+ line.split()[9:10])+"\n") 

dta_2path.close()
ws_2.close()
```

Any help in how to fix this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like 9:10 should be 5:6. But you're only extracting one column, so why not use `line.split()[1]` and `lines.split()[5]` ?

Comment: I used line.split()[1] and line.split()[5] but I get a syntax error in dta_2path.close(). Not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for line in dta_2path:
    if line.strip():
        cols = line.split()
        ws_2.write(cols[1] + "\t" + cols[5] + "\n")
```

Comment: I get the following error:   ws_2.write(cols[1], "\t", cols[5], "\n")
TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)

Comment: Grrr! You're right, have to use concatenation. I've edited it with '+' instead of ','

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the wrong indices. It should work if you use `line.split(" ")[1]` and `line.split(" ")[5]`.

Comment: I was adding the indices [1:2] and [9:10] because I was counting the spaces too. I changed to what you said but it didn't work.